# Broken DNS delegation

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory

```
           TEST: Delegations (Del)
              Delegation information for the zone: domainname.com.
                 Delegated domain name: domainname.com.domainname.com.
                    Warning: Delegation of DNS server c1ad001.domainname.com. is broken on IP:10.70.20.10
                    Error: DNS server: c1ad001.domainname.com. IP:10.70.20.10

                    [Broken delegation]

                    Warning: Delegation of DNS server c1ad002.domainname.com. is broken on IP:10.70.20.11
                    Error: DNS server: c1ad002.domainname.com. IP:10.70.20.11

                    [Broken delegation]

                    Warning: Delegation of DNS server coad001.domainname.com. is broken on IP:10.90.24.10
                    Error: DNS server: coad001.domainname.com. IP:10.90.24.10

                    [Broken delegation]

                    Warning: Delegation of DNS server coad002.domainname.com. is broken on IP:10.90.24.11
                    Error: DNS server: coad002.domainname.com. IP:10.90.24.11

                    [Broken delegation]

                    Warning: Delegation of DNS server lad001.domainname.com. is broken on IP:192.168.0.13
                    Error: DNS server: lad001.domainname.com. IP:192.168.0.13

                    [Broken delegation]

                    Warning: Delegation of DNS server lad002.domainname.com. is broken on IP:192.168.0.17
                    Error: DNS server: lad002.domainname.com. IP:192.168.0.17

                    [Broken delegation]


           TEST: Dynamic update (Dyn)
              Test record dcdiag-test-record added successfully in zone domainname.com
              Warning: Failed to delete the test record dcdiag-test-record in zone domainname.com
              [Error details: 9505 (Type: Win32 - Description: Unsecured DNS packet.)]
```

I get this error when running "dcdiag /v /c /d /e /s:coad001 >c:\dcdiag.txt" from a domain admin account as an admin. We have been having some DNS issues as of late, in particular, DNS records are just disappearing. What appears to be the issue and how do I fix it?

Comment: One thing I know. my domain name and forest name are the same. 
So the parts i removed should actually be
domainname.com.forestname.com which the domainname and forestname are the same. is this the issue?

Comment: Have you check this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4ba11324-85df-491f-824d-8a1fa60e9d2c/broken-dns-delegations?forum=winserverNIS) before?

Comment: Seems like you have a DNS record under `domainname.com` with the name `domainname.com`, you are better check the DNS records for the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. Under my domainname.com zone, I had a com, then domainname folder. It contained a record which would return xxx.domainname.com.domainname.com.

I deleted this record and created it under the domainname.com zone. The error went away and my connectivity to xxx didnt go away

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue this post helped me solve it!
- On DCDIAG results I was failing delegation for all 4 DNS servers. (Broken delegated domains & missing SRV record at DNS server....) 
- Looked under DNS Manager at this location:
    - servername / Forward Lookup Zone / (Domain Name) / COM / (Domain Name)
- Found an A record for some old server. 
- Deleted that record and the dcdiag returned a PASS under the delegation column.